# Portable router doesn't forward broadcast MDNS IPv6 messages

Tags: ipv6, local-area-network, mdns

I have a device (a motec ECU) that is connected throught a wired eth, which uses IPV6 with MDNS broadcast messages (ff02::fb) to get discoved in the network.

If I connect a laptop directly to the ecu port it gets discovered just fine and right away.

If instead I try to put a portable wifi router in the middle (tried the TP-Link TL-MR3020) the ecu doesn't get discovered.

I tried sniffing the traffic with wireshark and if I put the router in the middle I cannot see the MDNS message sent by the ecu, like if the router doesn't broadcast them...

I'm not an expert on IPv6, can someone please tell me if this is expected behavior or if I'm doing something wrong?

I've tried the router both in bridge and Access Point mode.

[Wireshark sniff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyQMn.png)

Comment: Link-local multicast cannot cross a router.